# How to modify cancan load and authorize resource to load resource using different id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

How can I modify load  and authorize resources to load resource using different id. for ex.

my routes is

```
http://localhost:3000/organization/user/12/event/20/edit
```

and in my event controller I am accessing event using `:event_id` and user using `:id`

Now in my event controller how can I modify `load_and_authorize_resource` use `:event_id` instead of `:id` for loading an event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource will only be loaded into an instance variable if it hasn't been already. This allows you to easily override how the loading happens in a separate before_filter.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_event
  load_and_authorize_resource

  private

  def find_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end
end
```

Read more in the docs: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions

Answer (score 4):

CanCan supports this through the `id_param` option:

From the [documentation](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L99):

```
  # [:+id_param+]
  #   Find using a param key other than :id. For example:
  #
  #   load_resource :id_param => :url # will use find(params[:url])
```

Therefore you can do the following in your situation:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :id_param => :event_id
```

Comment: +1. And if you want to selectively use different column like couple of inherited classes use different id, then there is `prepend` option https://amitpatel.xyz/cancancan-use-different-column-for-load-and-authorized-resource/